# feh: concurrent slideshow and montage modes

Tags: images, feh, image-viewer

I have sets of images that are related and that I would like to view in parallel (e.g., images A1, A2, A3, etc. constitute a sequence and images B1, B2, B3, etc. constitute a related sequence). I could prepare a montage of pairs (e.g., A1/B1, A2/B2, A3/B3) using `imagemagick` and view the sequence of pairs using `feh`'s slideshow mode. However, I would prefer to do this in one line and in memory (without writing intermediate files to disk). `Feh` has both slideshow and montage modes, but so far as I understand they are mutually exclusive. I have set up parallel windows with defined geometry (`feh -g`) and loaded image sequences into each; however, I cannot control both windows simultaneously to scroll through the image sets in parallel. I can automate the progression of images in each window (`feh -D`) but the two windows sometimes desynchronize and stopping or reversing the direction is cumbersome. Finally, I can pipe from `montage` to `feh -` but `feh` stops reading after the first image so I cannot simply generate the sequence of pairs in a loop and pipe the output of the loop to `feh`. Can what I am trying to do be accomplished with `feh` or perhaps with another image viewer available for linux?